# How to set Environment variables from Windows

Tags: windows, cmd, windows-10

What is the way to add environment variables in windows xp, 7, 8 , vista, 10 etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In Windows 7, 8, Vista or XP.

Find "My Computer" icon either on the desktop or in the start menu, right click on it, and select Properties item from the menu.
When you see the properties dialog box, click on the Environment Variables button then add it.

> In Windows 10 or higher, open cmd from start menu.

Then execute this command "`systemPropertiesAdvanced`"

Answer (score 1):

To view or change environment variables:

```
Right-click My Computer, and then click Properties.
Click the Advanced tab.
Click Environment variables.
Click one the following options, for either a user or a system variable:
    Click New to add a new variable name and value.
    Click an existing variable, and then click Edit to change its name or value.
    Click an existing variable, and then click Delete to remove it.
```