# How do you set the environment variable PROJECT_HOME and WORKON_HOME in Virtualenvwrapper for Windows?

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

How do you set the environment variable `PROJECT_HOME` and `WORKON_HOME` in `virtualenvwrapper` for Windows?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set Environment variables from Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32463212/how-to-set-environment-variables-from-windows)

Comment: [SETX](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3804979/7976758)

Answer (score 0):

i believe that one form is:
open cmd console 
then go into the direction that you want to set your enviromente variable
and then write `echo >> .env`
for other kind of variable you can do in the cmd

```
set var=polo
```

and to see the value put

```
echo %var%
```

some of the information is from here:
https://www.computerhope.com/echohlp.htm